# Read file of size more than 1.5gb

Tags: file

I need to look into the content of json file whose size is 1.8gb. Whenever I am trying to open it in any text editor its unable to open it. Is there any way to see the content either by breaking the file into smaller chunks or any other powerful editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this question should be migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or similar.
However, if you're under a Linux environment, you could do the following on the command line:

```
cat myfile.json | less
```

From the manpage of less:

> Also, less does not have to read the entire input file before  starting (...)

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget you can mark an answer as accepted by ticking the checkmark next to it!